# conditionally show and hide button using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Actually i am trying to disable the button when the task is running. Once the task finished loading i want to activate the button. Means paralally the sync icon spins when the task status is in 'In_progress' once the status changes to 'Completed' the spinner should be hidden and the button 'AutoCode Sync' should be activated. So how to achieve that one. For that i have written the below code:

```
<section *ngFor="let task of tasksRes">
    <nav>
        <span class="text-warning" *ngIf="task?.status == 'In_progress'"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span> 
    </nav>

    <div class="pull-right">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="open();" class="btn-w-md">
        AutoCode Sync
        </button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Can anyone please help me in this to achieve?
Thanks.

Comment: you can conditionally disable the button `[disabled]="task?.status=='In_progress'"`

Answer (score 3):

Use ngIf with your condition (status === Completed) to show/hide the button

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="open();" class="btn-w-md" *ngIf="task?.status == 'Completed'"">
    AutoCode Sync
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[hidden]` property on both the `spinner` and `button` but I'm not sure why you are using `*ngFor="let task of tasksRes"` do you get more than one buttons and spinner

```
<section *ngFor="let task of tasksRes">
    <nav [hidden]="task?.status == 'Completed'" >
        <span class="text-warning" *ngIf="task?.status == 'In_progress'"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span> 
    </nav>

    <div class="pull-right" [hidden]="task?.status == 'In_progress'">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="open();" class="btn-w-md">
        AutoCode Sync
        </button>
    </div>
</section>
```

this will act a toggle that shows and hides button based on the condition

You can either add a separate property as true and false to and read it based on your condition - hope this works - Happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

You can add any document attribute by `[attr.{{attribute}}]` in angular.

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <button mat-raised-button [attr.disabled]="task?.status == your_situation" color="primary" (click)="open();" class="btn-w-md">
    AutoCode Sync
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21388353)

Answer (score -1):

Disable the `button` conditionally using `[disabled]`

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="open();" class="btn-w-md" [disabled]="task?.status == 'In_progress'">
        AutoCode Sync
</button>
```